# Does apparmor in enforce mode still logs?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, apparmor

I'm using apparmor with Firefox (enforce).

I know that leaving in complain mode, apparmor will log what a certain program is doing. But I would like to know if it's possible to turn the "enforce" mode and still log any detail into somewhere?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `apparmor` in enforce mode logs to `/var/log/syslog`
You can watch for any changes:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i apparmor
```